# Стиль выделенного элемента ValueListEditor

Tags: c++builder

Первый элемент каждого ValueListEditor остается не закрашенным.

Подскажите как его закрасить?

[image: Скрин]

```
void __fastcall TEriFrameForm::ValueListEditorDrawCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow,
          TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
    //-закрашиваем нужные ячейки второго столбца
    if ( ACol==1) {
        ValueListEditor->Canvas->Brush->Color = clWebOrange;
        ValueListEditor->Canvas->Font->Color = clBlack;
        ValueListEditor->Canvas->FillRect( Rect );
        ValueListEditor->Canvas->TextOut( Rect.left + 4, Rect.top + 2, ValueListEditor->Cells[ACol][ARow] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Не должны ли индексы начинаться с 0?

Comment: Например, что означает в данном выражении ValueListEditor->Cells[1][ARow],  1 и ARow?

Comment: Событие DrawCell  вызывается при прорисовке компонента

ARow - номер перерисовываемой строки ACol - номер перерисовываемого столбца

ValueListEditor->Cells[1][ARow] - ячейка из второго столбца (правого) из строки ARow

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте изменить параметр `DefaultDrawing` на `FALSE`

Это поможет менять фон ячейки в функции `DrawGrid1DrawCell` только.

официальный пример

```
/*
The following code uses the bitmaps in an image list
component to draw the contents of each cell in a draw grid.
It draws a focus rectangle around the cell that has focus.
goDrawFocusSelect in the DrawGrid Options parameter must be
True to set focus on a cell.  The ImageList Draw method must
be called after DrawFocusRect. The OnSelectCell event handler
must implemented to return true.
*/
void __fastcall TForm1::DrawGrid1DrawCell(
  TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow, TRect &Rect, TGridDrawState State)
{
  long index = ARow * DrawGrid1->ColCount + ACol;
  DrawGrid1->Canvas->Brush->Color = clBackground;
  DrawGrid1->Canvas->FillRect(Rect);
  if (State.Contains(gdFocused))
  {
    DrawGrid1->Canvas->DrawFocusRect(Rect);
    Label1->Caption = "Cell " + IntToStr(int(index)) + " has the focus.";
  }
  ImageList1->Draw(
    DrawGrid1->Canvas, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, index, True);
}

void __fastcall TForm1::DrawGrid1SelectCell(TObject *Sender, int ACol, int ARow,
      bool &CanSelect)
{
  CanSelect= True;
}
```

[ссылка](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ValEdit_TValueListEditor_OnDrawCell.html#)